# Debugging Qt on Sitara won't launch

Tags: c++, qt, arm, remote-debugging

(Sorry for my bad english)

I'm working on Sitara (ARM arch) and my computer is under Debian with Qt4 and i'm developing with Qt Creator.

I've configure the cross-compilation, but i can't launch my project under debug :/

I've this message :

> Début du débogage
>   Unknown argument: --once
>   Échec du débogage
>   Le débogage est fini
>
> (Translate)
>   Start debugging 
>   Unknown argument: --once
>   Debugging failed
>   Debugging finish

Anyone know this problem ? Google doesn't

Have a good day

Answer (score 0, accepted):

--once is a parameter passed to GDBserver. If it is not understood, there is a chance that the GDBserver on the target is too old.

Comment: Probably, since the message, I've discover more problematic bug ...
And I've found a trap to got a debug :)

Thanks ;)